# mySql Join missing values for each group by

Tags: mysql

I have been bashing my head against the wall for a few days trying to figure out how to make this work.

I have a table "Customers" with the following

```
CustID  |   CatName
----------------
1        ModelX

1        ModelY

2        ModelX

3        ModelY
```

Then another table  "Prices"

```
ModelName  |  Price
--------------------
ModelX        $1000

ModelY        $500

ModelZ        $200
```

Desired output would be

```
ID  | ModelName |  Price
-------------------------
1      ModelX      $1000

1      ModelY      $500 

1      ModelZ      $200

2      ModelX      $1000

2      ModelY      $500

2      ModelZ      $200

3      ModelX      $1000

3      ModelY      $500

3      ModelZ      $200
```

I'm unclear how to get each non-matching CatName to each ID.  When I do an outer join, I will get the missing records but it will only be listed once and if there is a match for at least one CatName then it will not be matched to other CatNames where it isn't a match.., i.e.

```
CustID  |   CatName  | Price
----------------------------
1           ModelX     $1000

1           ModelY     $500

2           ModelX     $1000

2           ModelY     $500

3           ModelY     $500

(null)      ModelZ     $200
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us your current query

Answer (score 1):

The result you show should be a distinc on CutsID and cartesian product between Customers and Price

```
  select distinct * 
  from ( select  a.custID as custID, b.modelName, b.price  
          from customers as a, price b ) as mytable
  order by custID;
```

Comment: distinct isn't a function - the brackets are irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

Join every Prices row to each distinct id in Custoners:

```
select CustID, CatName, Price
from Prices, (select distinct CustID from Customers) c
```